# c# send pdf file from web service

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, webservice-client

I am new to C# and I have a web service which generates a pdf file containing barcode(using datamatrix). I want to send this pdf file over to the client as a byte[]

The web service contract is as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare ,UriTemplate = "/mymethod?param1={param1}&param2={param2}")]

byte[] mymethod(string param1, string param2)
```

At the client side, I read the response into a memory stream and then convert it into as array and write that to a file.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
byte[] responseBytes = ms.ToArray();
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```

The data written to the file is something like [37,80,25,....] which is the actual byte[] sent from the web service.

I have gone through many answers here but could not figure out how to get the actual bytes at the client side. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself.

I used a memory stream at the server side and loaded the byte[] into it.

At the client side, I read the memory stream and get the byte[] stored within it.